# log4j maven dependency download getting timed out

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I was trying to setup a web app using spring MVC. I'm getting "connection timed out" while maven tries to download dependencies for log4j.

Following is the dependency added to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Following is the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project FirstTestProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nikhil.projects:FirstTestProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.17 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project FirstTestProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nikhil.projects:FirstTestProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile)]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nikhil.projects:FirstTestProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile)]
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE (compile), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile)]
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:258)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:150)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.17 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.17 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1546)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1537)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1035)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:409)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:457)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:334)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:374)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:283)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:371)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:283)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Is your internet connection working fine..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

The version above is showing 0 bytes here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j

so could be a corrupt artifact

That may just be an issue on that page, so if that doesnt help check wherever you are running it from can access: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom

You may need to post your settings.xml if the above doesnt help.

Comment: Tried that link about an hour ago, it was not working. But call it a coincidence or whatever you want, it's working now. Tried to build my project, that is working too!
Thanks!!

Comment: thanks i simply changed the version from 1.2.17 to 1.2.16, and it worked. why 1.2.17 not working ?